# Regex to extract only digits after last whitespace

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

"Text text text $123,000,000 $456,000,000"

I was able to locate another regex solution to extract the characters on the end of the string after the last whitespace ([^\s]+$), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to exclude the commas and dollar sign.

I would like to extract only the digits while excluding any other non-digit character following the last whitespace in the string. Instead of "$456,000,000" I would like to extract "456000000"

Thank you very much for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` in `base R` - match all characters `.*` till one or more spaces (`\\s+`), replace with blank (`""`), then wrap with `gsub` to remove the `$` and `,`

```
gsub("[$,]", "", sub(".*\\s+", "", "Text text text $123,000,000 $456,000,000"))
#[1] "456000000"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This will save my organization tons of time.

Comment: Do you know of a way to match the text while retaining the whitespace between the words? Ideally, I would like to exclude the whitespace after the text. Expected output: "Text text text"

Comment: @uberbot `trimws()` is a handy base function that will remove extra whitespace from the start and end of strings.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas. I figured out a solution using the method akrun illustrated above.

trimws(gsub("[^a-zA-Z ] *", "", "Text text text $123,000,000 $456,000,000"))
[1] "Text text text"

Comment: @uberbot you don't need `gsub` with `trimws` i.e. `trimws("Text text text $123,000,000 $456,000,000", whitespace = "\\s*\\$.*")
[1] "Text text text"`